# minus query in sql developer

Tags: etl

I have two database connections in sql developer active lets say DB1 and DB2. I am working on ETL validation. So I want to check if data from Table1 of DB1 is populated correctly in Table2 of DB2.

To access tables from this two connections how can I write a query?
Any help on this will be helpful

Comment: What RDBMS is DB1 and DB2? One way could be to create a linked server (or similar) on one of them. Also what do you mean by 'populated correctly' what sort of things will you be checking.

Comment: DB1 and DB2 are "IBM DB2" databases. Populated correctly means if Tab1(Source) of DB1 has 10 records, Tab2(Target) of DB2 must have 10 records. If there is missing data, it can be found using MINUS.

Answer (score 0):

There are common ways to validate if the ETL is correct:

1. You can run 2 queries to calculate the line counts separately against to Table1@DB1 and Table2@DB2, and compare the line counts between them.
2. Or perform some aggregate functions, such as sum(), avg()...etc on tables in DB1/DB2.